# Regex not working Mongo DB + Spring Data + Java + Number

Tags: java, regex, spring, mongodb

```
  public List<Criteria> getCriteria(FiltersDto filtersDto) {
    List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<>();
    if (filtersDto.getId() != null && !filtersDto.getId().isEmpty())            
        criteria.add(Criteria.where("id").regex("^630$", "i"));}
```

**Java Code**

```
o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "$and" : [{ "_id" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : "^630$", "options" : "i"}}}]} fields: Document{{}}
```

Dont work for me. Help me please. I'm using a number like as String. When, I Use String works perfectly. But, when the field is number don't work. Please you comments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.